# Globally set length for all string variable in SAS

Tags: sas

Is there a global option to override the default length options for string in SAS? The only way that I have found is by setting the `length` statement within a data or proc step. This is not ideal for me as I would need to rework a large amount of code.

Comment: The answer is no, but if you post examples of the type of code you are running you might get suggestions for how to handle those specific situations.

Comment: Do you want to change the lengths of variables that are in existing data sets (in a permanent library)?

Comment: Thanks for the info! I will just do it the long way and eventually write a macro for it!